# SSL Certificate Error when using an API - troubleshooting methods

Tags: python, api, ssl, ssl-certificate, darksky

I cannot access the Darksky API (weather forecast API) from a python script on my home internet while it runs fine on the office internet. Also, when I paste the Darksky url on a web browser it works fine, too. I read somewhere that both office internet and web browser have their own intermediate certificates while my home internet may not.

This is the error message:

> 'HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.darksky.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /forecast/*key*/*lat*,*long*?units=us&exclude=hourly,minutely,daily (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))']

I'm on a Linux machine. I've tried downloading PEM(cert) and PEM(chain) certificate files from the web browser and saving them to "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates" and "/etc/ssl/certs" folders. I then ran the "sudo update-ca-certificates" command. I've also tried changing the file extension to ".crt", but no luck.

What other troubleshooting methods are there? Thank you!